# How to completely uninstall MATLAB?

Tags: software-center, update-manager, matlab

Recently, I installed MATLAB from the Ubuntu Software and uninstalled afterwards. However, when I do a software update via Software Updater, it shows me the following and disallow me to continue the update process. How can I completely remove the MATLAB software?

[image]

I have tried the following command but now workable.
[image]

When I execute `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, the following is shown.
[image]

Comment: Did you actually install Matlab from Mathworks (not from Ubuntu Software) ? If not you could create a bogus directory like `/opt/matlab` and enter that when asked for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no uninstaller for MATLAB on UNIX or Linux. To remove MATLAB you simply need to delete the MATLAB installation following the instructions below:

1. If you are running a license manager for MATLAB, shut down the license manager using the `lmdown` script located in MATLAB's etc directory. If this folder does not exist, you are not running the FlexNet license manager. For example:

   ```
   [root@localhost ~] /usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/etc/lmdown
   ```
2. You should also remove any license manager files in the `/var/tmp` directory. These files should begin with `lm_TMW`, e. g.:

   ```
   [root@localhost ~] rm /var/tmp/lm_TMW*
   ```
3. Remove the entire root MATLAB directory using the `rm -rf` command, e. g.:

   ```
   [root@localhost ~] rm -rf /usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b
   ```
4. Remove any symlinks to MATLAB binaries on the path, e. g.:

   ```
   [root@localhost ~] rm /usr/local/bin/matlab /usr/local/bin/mcc /usr/local/bin/mex /usr/local/bin/mbuild
   ```

[Source](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102428-how-do-i-uninstall-matlab-products-on-a-unix-or-linux-machine#answer_111774)

Comment: At least as of MATLAB 2019a, you'll also want to `rm /usr/local/bin/deploytool`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get remove matlab-support
```

I got the same problem, and it seemed to have happened because I've installed a MATLAB support tool before I installed MATLAB itself.

Answer (score 0):

For me the recommendation of

```
sudo apt-get remove matlab-support
```

with and additional command line

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

worked.

I explain:
First:

```
sudo apt-get remove matlab-support
```

after this command line the terminal show you a error message and suggest you to use

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Second:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

by typing this command line will show you a screen like the second one shown in this post, click on "cancel" and wait.

Third: well nothing, the system in the previous step had to remove the package.